# NameError: name 'win' is not defined with tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

After Executing This code i am getting error win not found running tkinter from different function is important as its a homework

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
def zui(kaj,saj):
    zun=kaj
    kaj=kaj+"=tk.Tk()"
    exec(kaj)
    saj=zun+".title('"+saj+"')"
    exec(saj)
def zabel(self,naj,iaj,oaj,baj,gaj,taj):
    spsp=self+"="+"Label("+naj+", text='"+iaj+"', bg='"+oaj+"', height="+gaj+", width="+taj+",fg='"+baj+"')"
    spsp=str(spsp)
    exec(spsp)
def zosition(qak,iak,nak):
    sspp=qak+".grid(row="+iak+", column="+nak+")"
    exec(sspp)
def zainzoop(tak):
    sft=tak+".mainloop()"
    exec(sft)
zui("win","zahid app")
zabel("label","win","hello world","white","black","4","10")
zosition("win","1","1")
zainzoop("win")
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/PyProjects/Patient Data Entry/hello.py", line 20, in <module>
    zabel("label","win","hello world","white","black","4","10")
  File "c:/PyProjects/Patient Data Entry/hello.py", line 12, in zabel
    exec(spsp)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'win' is not defined
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `exec` l ike this. It makes the code almost impossible to understand.

Comment: Please follow a tutorial to learn how to code: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/  exploring the language on your own going in the direction you are currently will make it hard to imporove yourself.

Comment: using keyword self as variable is as well not the best idea, you might run into various issues if you were defining a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very weird way on using tkinter, anyway who am I to judge. `exec()` takes a `globals()` argument to make the declaration `global`. This is how the exec should look like:

```
exec(spsp,globals())
exec(sspp,globals())
exec(sft,globals())
```

and then in the end, `zosition()` should be called like:

```
zosition("label","1","1")
```

Just in case your curious on how it would normally look like:

```
import tkinter as tk

kaj = tk.Tk()
kaj.title('zahid app')

spsp = tk.Label(kaj,text='Hello World',bg='white',fg='black',height=4,width=10)
spsp.grid(row=1,column=1)

kaj.mainloop() #much easier right?
```